# Using ENV Variables to launch container in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

My docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
services:
 my-service:
  image: ${PYTHON_IMAGE}:${PY_VERSION}
```

these ENV variables are declared in WSL, however when I use VS code remote container to launch the development in the container, it will fail, I tried using WSLENV to assign the variables and tested within a session between WSL and Windows, the variables are properly shared but still couldnt get the variables assigned when the container is created/build by VSCode

Appreciate your response 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right now I get it working using
[WLSENV](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/)

added the following line to .bashrc

```sh
export WSLENV=$WSLENV:VAR_NODE_IMAGE_NAME/u:VAR_NODE_VERSION/u
cmd.exe /C  set | grep  '^VAR' | tr '=' ' ' | awk '{printf "SETX %s %s\n", $1, $2}' | cmd.exe >> /dev/null
```

this will add the env vars to Windows when I launch my terminal